# Upload files from two different applications to same folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

Is it possible to upload files from different web applications in a same folder.
Application A corresponds to a register page, and application B administrator can track every person is register in application A.
The problem is that administrator of app B cannot see the documents uploaded in app A since they where uploaded in a different folder.
How can I save the uploaded files of app A into de folder of app B.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of doing this is to have a common folder outside of both applications that they can both see.  Inside of IIS you set this up as a virtual directory in each application.

From the applications perspective, it looks like the folder is local to it's root path.  However, it's physically stored elsewhere.

**Steps**

1. Go to the file system on your web server.
2. Create a directory somewhere to hold your uploads.  Give your app pool rights to read and write files to that directory.
3. Open IIS Manager on the web server.
4. Navigate to Application A.
5. Right click on the site and select Add Virtual Directory
6. Enter an alias for it and set the path to the directory you created in step 2.
7. Do steps 4,5 and 6 for Application B.

From Application A, change your code to save your files to that directory.  From Application B change the code to pull the files from that directory.

Comment: Can you please provide the steps to do it?